# android:allowBackup="true" but not creating backup

Tags: android, android-backup-service

My understanding is this is a fairly simple setup.  I have in my manifest -

```
android:allowBackup="true"
android:fullBackupContent="true"
```

But with this app installed, looking in             Backup - account - Apps the app is not listed.  I have been using the app for a week or so, with sharedPrefs changing plenty.

This app is pretty much a carbon copy of another app, with package name and app name changed, the other app is listed, this one isn't?  Device is a Pixel XL.

Any ideas why?  Are there any other settings I should check?

(Also, can someone please confirm it will only restore the data to a phone running Android 6.0 or newer?)

Thanks!